# Entity Framework Core get data from stored procedure and then convert into view model without DbSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a function in the repository, `GetForms`, the purpose of the function is to call a stored procedure and return rows with data. Everything is working fine until now.

**Function**

```
public IEnumerable<FormBO> GetForms() 
{
      var id = "1"
      var Query= _context.FormBO.FromSqlRaw("dbo.SP_Core  @pin_ID={0}", id)
                                .AsNoTracking().ToList(); //3K line of sp
      return Query;
}
```

**Model**

```
public class FormBO
{
    [Key]
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public int? secondid { get; set; }
    ......
}
```

**DbContext**

Added this code, so context thinks it is a table in the database and, I don't have to do more stuff

```
 public virtual DbSet<FormBO> FormBO { get; set; }
```

**The problem**

Whenever we scaffold the database and the db context, it regenerates all the files and code, so it removes the

```
  public virtual DbSet<FormBO> FormBO { get; set; }
```

And we have to add this line manually is there any way I can change the logic, so I don't have to add this code (`DBset<FormBO>`) to `DbContext` every time a dba updates the database...

**What I found**

I found that if I change the model to ".Database" and `FromSqlRaw` to `ExecuteSqlRaw`, but it is just returning the count as int not a list of rows.

```
public IEnumerable<FormBO> GetForms() 
{
    var id = "1"
    var Query = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("dbo.SP_Core  @pin_ID={0}", id)
                                 .AsNoTracking().ToList(); //3K line of sp
     return Query;
}
```

If it is possible it automatically add the `DBSet` to context whenever we update the code which I don't think we will able to do.

**or**

Get the query result without the dbset model and then I will use foreach loop to add it in FormBO model it is just 10 rows

Comment: You could try to put your extra entities in a partial class, but I would not scaffold "every time dba update database". I surely prefer to update manually the entities rather then loose all the customization with a new scaffold.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

Since the table doesn't actually exist in the database, the built in scaffolding process won't attempt to create it.

However you could probably replace the `IScaffoldingModelFactory` service, with an implementation that extends `RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory`, and use the code-first fluent api to define meta data for tables that don't really exist.

You could probably use this type of approach to define types for all table values in the database. Since EF Core 5 is adding support for table values, maybe they'll do it for you, but I haven't tested that.

```cs
public class MyModelFactory : RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory
{
    public MyModelFactory(
        IOperationReporter reporter, 
        ICandidateNamingService candidateNamingService, 
        IPluralizer pluralizer, 
        ICSharpUtilities cSharpUtilities, 
        IScaffoldingTypeMapper scaffoldingTypeMapper, 
        LoggingDefinitions loggingDefinitions) 
    : base(reporter, candidateNamingService, pluralizer, cSharpUtilities, scaffoldingTypeMapper, loggingDefinitions)
    {
    }

    protected override ModelBuilder VisitDatabaseModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DatabaseModel databaseModel)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<FormBO>(entity =>
        {
            // ...
        });

        return base.VisitDatabaseModel(modelBuilder, databaseModel);
    }
}

    services.AddDbContextPool<ContextType>(o =>
    {
        o.ReplaceService<IScaffoldingModelFactory, MyModelFactory>();
        // ...
    });
```

Of course there's an easy answer too. The scaffolded context is a partial class. Just define your other DbSet in another source file.